# Kendo UI TreeList select all child nodes

Tags: jquery, kendo-ui, telerik

I'm using the [TreeList](http://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/treelist/index) from KendoUI, I have a column that contains a tick/cross image. So far I have set it to toggle the tick/cross on click of a row and also toggle the direct children on the selected node. I have found a way to toggle all children 3 levels deep (In the example of the kendo page, this would be from Daryl to Buffy).

However since I will be using TreeLists with up to 8 levels deeps, maybe more. I need to toggle the tick/cross of all the children of the selected node, regardless of how many levels deep it goes.

Below is the code I'm using so far, I don't think adding in 8 more levels of for and if statements is the best way to go.

```
 $('#treelist td[role="gridcell"]').click(function(e) {

var treelist = $('#treelist').data("kendoTreeList");

if($(this).has("img[src='greentick.png']").length > 0) {
    $(this).find('img').attr("src","redcross.png");

    var selectedRow = treelist.select();
    var dataItem = treelist.dataItem(selectedRow);
    var rowID = dataItem.id;

    var data = treelist.dataSource.data(); //Array of all data rows
    var children = [];
    console.log(data);

    for(var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {

        var parentID = data[i].parentId;
        if(parentID == rowID) { //If this row is a child of the selected row
            children.push(data[i].id);
            data[i].working = "<img src='redcross.png' />";

            if(data[i].hasChildren) {
                var childParentID = data[i].id;  //Parent ID to check against child nodes of current node

                for(var j = i; j < (data.length - i); j++) {

                    if(data[j].parentId == childParentID) {
                        data[j].working = "<img src='redcross.png' />";
                    }
                }
            }
        }       
    }
    treelist.refresh();

} else if($(this).has("img[src='redcross.png']").length > 0) {
    $(this).find('img').attr("src","greentick.png");
}

});
```

For reference this is what a single dataItem looks like in the array returned by the Treelist (var data in my case). var data contains an array which contains an array for each row.

```
Name: "Daryl Sweeney"
Phone: "(555) 924-9726"
Position: "CEO"
_events: Object
_loaded: true
dirty: false
hasChildren: true
id: 1
parent: ()
parentId: null
uid: "16a87dbd-8ddf-41f4-b69e-38822a527deb"
working: "<img src='greentick.png' id='test' />"
__proto__: i.extend.i
```

Comment: Do your list uses async load for child lists ?

Comment: I don't think so, at the moment I'm just using the sample TreeList grid from the kendo site here - http://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/treelist/index